# Resize div including border-bottom to fit other box when resizing browser

Tags: html, css, resize, position

This is my first question and I am very new at this, so forgive my ignorance.

I am creating a website with a footer in a `div` with a `border-bottom`. In the footer there are two `div`, one at each side. When I resize the window in the browser, the right column moves under the left column. That is alright, but the `border-bottom` goes right across the `div`.
I have tried with `position: relative` and `absolute` and `overflow` and nothing.

This is the code simplified:

```
<div class="footer">

  <div class="footerleft">
    <p>content here with lists and links</p>
  </div> 

  <div class="footerright">
    <p>content here with two more boxes and lists and links</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is the CSS simplified:

```
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    clear: both;
    border-top: #fbd1b9 5px solid;
}    
.footerleft {
    float: left;
}    
.footerright {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Why use a `div` with the class name "footer" instead of just using the `<footer> `tag?

Comment: The border stays on top of footerleft and footerright, which is what I would expect.  How would you like it to look?

Comment: Please explain better to help you.